# How to use the Podlove client on a vanilla Jekyll page?

Tags: javascript, jekyll

Following the Podlove (JavaScript podcast player) docu on https://docs.podlove.org/podlove-web-player/installation.html I try to use the Podlove player on a fresh Jekyll page:

```
jekyll new my-awesome-site
cd my-awesome-site
mkdir -p assets/podcasts
cp /tmp/audio-file.mp3 assets/podcasts/audio-file.mp3
rm index.md
```

I create this `index.html` file:

```
---
layout: home
---

<h1>Podlove Test</h1>

<script src="https://cdn.podlove.org/web-player/embed.js"></script>

<script>
  podlovePlayer('#example', '/assets/podcasts/audio-file.mp3');
</script>
```

Fire up Jekyll with `bundle exec jekyll serve` and browse the URL http://localhost:4000

The result:
[image: Screenshot of the browser]

The JavaScript console shows this error-message:
[image]

I follow the documentation but something is missing.

What do I have to do to get a player like displayed on https://podlove.org/podlove-web-player/ ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vanilla embedding for the Webplayer is documented here: https://docs.podlove.org/podlove-web-player/embedding.html

In your current implementation the dom reference is not included in the html. Also the player only accepts a [JSON configuration](https://docs.podlove.org/podlove-web-player/config.html), currently you are passing in a plain audio file reference.

```
<div id="example"></div>

<script src="embed.js"></script>
<script>
  podlovePlayer('#example', './fixtures/example.json');
</script>
```